# Store update value in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

i got two values i.e.**company and id**  from navigation.

```
let id = props.route.params.oved;
console.log("id-->",id);
let company = props.route.params.company;
console.log("company--->",company);
```

i got two values as a integer like this:--

```
id-->1
comapny-->465
```

i want to conert these two values as in string.it should be look like this:---

```
id--->"1"
company--->"465"
```

How can i achieve these two values as in string?

[image: if i am giving input 1 in that textInput and click on of the card(lets say first card i.e.465 them i am getting those two values in navigation as in interger that i have mention above.so each time i am getting updated values.)]

**Description of the image**:---

if i am giving input 1 in that textInput and click on  the card(lets say first card i.e.465 then i am getting those two values in navigation as in interger that i have mention above.so each time i am getting updated values.

i am getting updated values from navigation.

so i want to store those values in redux.

How can i store the update values getting from navigation in Redux?

Comment: You can store anything in redux. As per your first question, conversion to string can be with the built in toString() function

Comment: how can i store?what is the action and reducer file for those ?

Comment: It’s just like any other value in your store. The redux tutorial is quite helpful https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store

Comment: could you please write code for redux to store values..so i will get clarification..

Comment: An example can be found here https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers

Comment: i didnt get any..could you please write code for redux?it will help me alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an Integer to a string using `.toString()` method in JavaScript.

```
let id = props.route.params.oved.toString();
console.log("id-->",id);
let company = props.route.params.company.toString();
console.log("company--->",company);
```

now your console log would look like.

```
id--->"1"
company--->"465"
```

For more details follow [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-tostring-function/#:%7E:text=The%20toString()%20method%20in,representing%20the%20specified%20Number%20object.&text=The%20toString()%20method%20is,in%20above%20syntax%20using%20the%20%27.)